# Does EntityFrameworkCore only retrieve to a certain depth in the nested objects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have a class called ConnectionsBank that has a list of Connections and a list of Connection Categories.  The Connections class has a collection of PhoneNumber and ConnectionCategories.  PhoneNumber class has a PhoneNumberType.

In my controller I have a Get that uses AutoMapper 7:

```
        var result = await ControllerRepository.GetConnectionManagerAsync(connectionManagerdID);


        return Ok(Mapper.Map<ConnectionManagerViewModel>(result));
```

The following is the return JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "jobSeekerID": 1,
  "connections": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "completeName": {
        "firstName": "Mary",
        "lastName": "Jane"
      },
      "address": {
        "street": "1 Main Street",
        "city": "Rushville",
        "state": "IN",
        "country": "USA",
        "zipCode": "99999"
      },
      "phoneNumbers": [
        {
          "phNumber": "317-922-8823",
          "phoneType": null
        }
      ],
      "categories": null
    }
  ],
  "connectionCategories": [
    {
      "categoryName": "FIRST CONNECTION CATEGORY"
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "SECOND CONNECTION CATEGORY"
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that "categories" and "phoneType" are null.  The database has the data in the tables.  Why would this happen?  I am using EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: You need to ask EF to include the grandchildren using the include method when querying the context. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data